# Pattern attribute can't be used in input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some boxes of articles that will display a modal to the user when clicked, 
what I'm trying to do is to have a load more button since the page might have plenty of boxes in the future. when I use this code only one div is displayed and the loadmore button is not working.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>
<div id="mybox">Content</div>

<a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>

<p class="totop"> 
    <a href="#top">Back to top</a> 
</p>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
/*
    Load more content with jQuery - May 21, 2013
    (c) 2013 @ElmahdiMahmoud
*/   

$(function () {
    $("#mybox").slice(0, 4).show();
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#mybox:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
        if ($("#mybox:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
});

$('a[href=#top]').click(function () {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('.totop a').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.totop a').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: You should never use the same ID multiple times, An ID should be unique. Use class for multiple occasions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `id` should always be unique and never exist more than ones per page on your website. If you change your `id="mybox"` to `class="mybox"` and change the jquery to match it, then it works just fine.

**Demo**

```js
$(function () {
    $(".mybox").slice(0, 4).show();
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".mybox:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
        if ($(".mybox:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
});

$('a[href=#top]').click(function () {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('.totop a').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.totop a').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

```css
.mybox{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>
<div class="mybox">Content</div>

<a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>

<p class="totop"> 
    <a href="#top">Back to top</a> 
</p>
```

Comment: still not borking with my divs, i put the class name of the whole box which has many divs inside it, but does not work

Comment: I found this example and i like it but they only put three lines of code!! do you have any idea how to use it? https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/examples/infinite-scroll/#shortcode

Comment: Yes I do, but its not a coding service, But use the Demo in my answer then you can see the working solution

Comment: thanks works perfect! :) but the page scrolls down when i click on loadmore, can i prevent this?

Comment: is there a way to make the loadmroe button visible ONLY if there is anything more to show?